# Name Error: name 'x' is not defined when working with function

Tags: python

I have 3 dataframes that I'm working with that has the same column names and that I'm working on merging them.  The first column is for the dataframes I want the same.  The rest of the columns are years, and I wanted to add a letter to each of years to distinguish between the dataframes.  I was able to do this manually without any issues.  But when I tried defining a function, I get the following error

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined.

This is my initial attempt without defining a function.  dfyears is the dataframe I'm trying to change the columns names with.  The first column 'City_State', I want to keep the same, and the rest I want to add a letter behind depending on the dataframe.

```
dfyearlist = (dfyears.columns[1:].values.tolist())
dfcols = [(dfyears.columns[0])]
for i in dfyearlist:
    dfcols.append(i + 'r')
dfyears.columns = dfcols
```

Here's the first 3 lines of my output:

```
        City_State        2010r        2011r        2012r        2013r  \
0     New York, NY  1771.666667  1753.384615  1803.615385  1955.384615   
1  Los Angeles, CA  2190.333333  2185.076923  2185.000000  2242.692308   
2      Houston, TX  1198.666667  1195.538462  1197.846154  1252.692308   

         2014r        2015r        2016r        2017r        2018r  
0  2124.000000  2271.230769  2331.846154  2337.384615  2295.846154  
1  2331.384615  2522.692308  2687.000000  2798.307692  2883.153846  
2  1322.076923  1411.461538  1439.461538  1423.615385  1432.923077
```

But when I tried defining a function:

```
def changecolumnnames(s, x):
    templist = [s.columns[1:].values.tolist()]
    returnlist = [(s.columns[0])]
    for i in templist:
        returnlist.append(i + str(x))
    s.columns = returnlist 

zillrentyears = changecolumnnames(zillrentyears, r)
```

I get:

> NameError: name 'r' is not defined.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you are calling your function like : changecolumnnames(zillrentyears, r), where you define your variable 'r'?

Comment: Quote r. It's a character, not a variable `hangecolumnnames(zillrentyears, "r")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` is a string and you're trying to pass it as a variable.

You need to change your function to `hangecolumnnames(zillrentyears, "r")` and then inside the function you can call `returnlist.append(i + x)` without using `str`.

Comment: I get a snytax error for putting the quotation mark inside the function parameters.

Comment: ```  
File "<ipython-input-244-2184d1aad00a>", line 3
    def changecolumnnames(s, "x"):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just to clarity, the up arrow is pointing at "x"

Comment: You don't make `x` a string in the function itself, you pass 'r' as a string: `hangecolumnnames(zillrentyears, "r")`. `x` is still a variable.

Comment: I've tried this as well, and the error I get is:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Right, in this code `returnlist.append(i + x)`, `i` is a list, so you need to change `templist = [s.columns[1:].values.tolist()]` to `templist = s.columns[1:].values.tolist()`

Comment: Okay I get a new error message now.
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 19 elements

Answer (score 0):

x is not defined outside of changecolumnnames

You provide r as an input to changecolumnnames. r is your x outside of changecolumnnames

Comment: My bad, that was a typo on my end.  It should read name 'r' is not defined.